# Rotate a image and fill screen in python

Tags: python, rotation, python-imaging-library

I am trying to rotate a photo that would fill the whole frame (in this case a 720x480 window). When i use the default Image.rotate function from PIL/PILLOW like in the code fragment below:

```
                    file = Image.open("test.jpg")
                    out = file.rotate(45, expand = 1)
                    out.save(work_dir+foreground,quality=100)
```

I get this result in photo 1 that rotates the photo within the box. 
What I'd like to do is rotate it so that it fills the whole box (i dont mind the cropping) like in photo 2 Is there a way to do that? 
[image: Default Pillow Rotation]

[image: Goal Rotation]

Comment: You'd have to loop through each pixel around the edge and detect black or alpha channel pixels (depending on your picture). Then you'd have to use the [Image.resize](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) function.

Answer (score 0):

The `expand` argument within `out = file.rotate(45, expand = 1)` should be set to false.

Comment: this  unfortunately just fits the photo into the bounding box further

Answer (score 0):

Found a cheap solution for square images:

```
def rotate_image_square(im, deg):
    im2 = im.rotate(deg, expand=1)
    im =  im.rotate(deg, expand=0)

    width, height = im.size
    assert (width == height)

    rads = math.radians(deg)
    new_width = width - (im2.size[0]-width)

    left  = top    = int((width - new_width)/2)
    right = bottom = int((width + new_width)/2)

    return im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
```